# Unknown database type enum requested,Doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

when i want to generate Entity from data base i have this Error:

```
Unknown database type enum requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform may not support it
```

how can i resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Doctrine does not maps the ENUM database type to Doctrine type. Anyway, there are few workarounds exists. Check out the [official documentation](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/mysql-enums.html) about enums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to do something like this in the `onBootstrap` module of your `Module.php`, to tell Doctrine to treat your `enum` like a string

```
$em = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
$platform = $em->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform();
$platform->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('enum', 'string');
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line to your **bootstrap.php**

```
$entityManager->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('enum', 'string');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to work with enums and don't convert them to strings, you should implement your custom type (it's really not a big deal).
See [enter link description here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/custom-mapping-types.html)

But also, you **have to** extend list of types on your platform.
So, simplest way to do that - override useless method \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::getMappedDatabaseTypes with your own so like that:

```
class EnumType extends Type
{
    const NAME = "enum";

    // ... (your implemented methods)

    public function getMappedDatabaseTypes(AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return ['enum'];
    }
}
```

Have a fun :)